# Python how to do .values().values() of a dictionary of dictionaries of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My python dictionary structure is like this:

```
ips[host][ip]
```

each row of ips[host][ip] looks like this:

```
[host, ip, network, mask, broadcast, mac, gateway, ip_ver, status]
```

Thus the keys are also stored in the rows. This dictionary is processed heavily and used for other heavier processing as well. Once this dictionary is considered final, I have to output the rows to a database.

The output function is complicated by output optimization and other programming features like conflict treatment (e.g. what do automatically do when there is a primary key conflict). In addition, the output function is used for many other dictionaries/tables.

The output function requires a list, not a dictionary (which is why the keys are also in the ips dictionary). All other dictionaries I send to the output function work by doing this, since they are dictionaries of lists:

```
locations = am_output.loc.values()
```

However, this ips dictionary is a dictionary of dictionaries of lists. I thought this would work:

```
ips = am_output.ips.values().values()
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: There are 4 million records it would be huge. The first two code sections above shows the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension would do:

```
[y for x in ips.values() for y in x.values()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> ips = {'a' : {1: 2, 3: 4},
...     'b': {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}}
>>> [y for x in ips.values() for y in x.values()]
[2, 4, 'b', 'd']
```